# How to access data some specific Controllers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

For sharing data with all views I read in documentation we can create

`View::share('key', 'value');`

I found that also we can make View Composer to share data with only some specific views.

But how to actually share data with only some specific controllers?

Few controllers we list to have injected some variables, objects arrays etc ready to use.

One Idea that comes to my mind is to create for them middleware... But I don't think it should be done something this way

Looking for this in documentation and web but cannot found, so how actually share data only with some specific controllers that we want to?

Comment: why not you use session for this ?

Comment: What kind of data you want to pass into the controller?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo using session for this will not be an overcharging solution for entire app?

Comment: @Bas some variables, array, object

Comment: @Bocki Then probaly use Trait, example https://www.conetix.com.au/blog/simple-guide-using-traits-laravel-5 , you can use it in the controller you wish

Comment: Using sessions for this is not overkill. It's exactly what they are for.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Where to set this sessions variables? In middleware? Or service providers? As I think service provider will make session variables for all my controllers, not only some specific?

Comment: @Bas But as I see traits can give me use some categorized methods when I want to, not inject set variables of my own method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help for you:

Some snippets from conetix.com.au/blog/simple-guide-using-traits-laravel-5
You can use `use ExampleCode;` in the controller you wish

```
<?php 
namespace App\Traits;

trait ExampleCode
{
    public function asd()
    {
        return [1,2,3];
    }
}

namespace App\Something;

use App\Traits\ExampleCode;

class Someclass
{
    use ExampleCode;

    public $yourarray;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->yourarray = $this->asd();
    }

    public function hi(){
         dd($this->yourarray);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice :) these traits. But as I see it allows me to create stored methods in it that i can use later in controllers. But can't I use it to set variables in methods that uses traits?

Comment: @BockiZong do you have an example of a set vars you want to use in your controller?

Comment: Let's assume in Controller1, Controller2, Controller3 I want to have already injected var ready to use of array named $asd. Something like `$asd = array(1,2,3);` Already accessible in these three controllers

Answer (score 0):

If multiple controllers need to have access to the same data, then you may want to consider creating a base controller that they inherit from and setting that data in the constructor of the controller.

Alternatively you can store it in the session and retrieve it from there in the controllers that need it.

Comment: Take not that if you do this, you cant access `Auth::user()` in the constructor, you'll have to use a middleware instead.

Comment: Where to set these session variables? Middleware you mean? that groups some controllers? Or maybe is there way for Service provider to only assign them some controllers? not all of them?

Comment: Wherever is most appropriate. If it is only going to be accessible to logged in users, it might make sense to set it during login, after the user has successfully authenticated. Or you could trigger an event for login and have a listener for that event set the value in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use decomposition for this purpose. Write some service class for your data, [bind it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding) to your service container and then [inject it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#resolving) into controllers constructor or action methods.